# Magento error Class ../validator does not exist

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento2

I just installed Magento2 platform. The admin page was blank showing gray screen without anything. I enabled the error to be shown then its displaying this error and I didn't found any solution or reason of it:

**There has been an error processing your request**

> Class Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator does not
>   exist

Comment: Did you check if the file is there?

Comment: Yes its there 
Actually I only added this code to it to enable displaying errors details
Also I try remove it but still same error 


foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    // Add this line
    $realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
    // and replace `$directory` with `$realDirectory`
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Check the following path. If your magento admin page is blank check the path:
`magento_root_dir\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php`

And change the following line:

```
if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
    return true;
}
```

to:

```
if (0 === strpos($path, $directory)) {
     return true;
}
```

If the folder still can't be located, check the path below too:
`magento_root_dir\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php`

Answer (score 0):

What is the Magento2 version that you are installing?

Could you set Mode to developer and send me the trace on var/log/system.log?

See how to set Magento2 modes [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html)

Thanks

Comment: I'm using Magento2 version 2.3.0
I have reinstalled it, The error is same (displaying blank admin page).
Convert it to developer mode and showing this error:

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/mymagento/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js'

with some other lines....

Comment: Did you try to find this mymagento/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtm ? Is it existing?

Comment: Actually, I deleted the whole project and reinstall it again. the error not appearing to me again.
I would like to thank you and appreciate your interesting for help.
Because I didn't found a way to delete the question from here so it's still here.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 generates factory class inside generated folder.  If generated folder has file write permission or ownership permission it can't generate factory class. For Magento 2, *generated* folder is in magento root path.

Run following commands and try:

```
chmod -R 777 generated/ var/
chown -R magento_user:magento_user generated/`
```